# Insert Data Into Database Using AngularJS

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm currently developing an AngularJS project, which has a form and on form submit the form data is pushed to a sql database.

I have successfully managed to get the AngularJS project connecting to the sql database, but the data from the form is not inserting itself into the table columns and instead is displaying empty - please see attached for a visual explanation.

Question, why is my data not inserting into the sql and how do I correct my code to get this working?

Any and all advice would be appreciated, thank you.

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  console.log($scope.form);
  $http.post('XXX/submit.php', {'id':'3','coachName':'1','contractArea':'2','attendance':'4'})
  .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
    console.log('Success');
  });
};
```

**PHP**

```
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

  $coachName = mysql_real_escape_string($data->coachName);
  $contractArea = mysql_real_escape_string($data->contractArea);
  $id = mysql_real_escape_string($data->id);
  $attendance = mysql_real_escape_string($data->attendance);

  mysql_connect('XXX','XXX','XX');
  mysql_select_db('XX');
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO participants(`id`, `coachName`, `contractArea`, `attendance`)VALUES('".$id."','".$coachName."','".$contractArea."','".$attendance."')");
```

**SQL**
[image]

[image]

**PHP, Update 1**

```
  $servername = "XXX";
  $username = "XXX";
  $password = "XXX";
  $dbname = "XXX";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO participants (id,coachName, contractArea, attendance) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $iddb, $coachName, $contractArea, $attendance);

  $id = "1";
  $coachName = "2";
  $contractArea = "3";
  $attendance = "4";
  $stmt->execute();

  echo "Success";

  $stmt->close();
  $conn->close();
```

**AngularJS, Update 2**

```
  var variableName = {id:'1', coachName:'AA', contractArea:'BB', attendance:'CC'};
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "xxx/submit.php",
    data:  variableName,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  }).then(function(){
    console.log('Success');
  },function(){
    console.log('Error');
  });
```

**PHP, Update 2**

```
$servername = 'xxx';
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
$dbname = 'xxx';

$conn = new Mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  mail( "xxx@xxx.com", "DB connect error", $db->connect_errno . ": " . $db->connect_error );
}

$id = '1';
$coachName = $_POST['coachName'];
$contractArea = $_POST['contractArea'];
$attendance = $_POST['attendance'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO participants (id, coachName, contractArea, attendance) VALUE(?, ?, ?, ?)' );
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $id, $coachName, $contractArea, $attendance);

$stmt->execute();

echo 'Success';

$stmt->close();


$conn->close();
```

Comment: OMG stop using the `mysql_` extension already

Comment: I'm following an online tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9KLLXtJZZM I do apologies!

Comment: Have you got any better suggestions @AlonEitan ?

Comment: [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [preperd steatments](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) are much more secured (With an emphasis on prepered steatments, instead of escaped strings)

Comment: And BTW, that `mysql_query();` line should be removed

Comment: Why $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
When you send POST data,into php you have to get them using $_POST array

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan only when data is sent form encoded but default for angular `$http` is to send as `application/json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a couple hours, a lot of post reading and support from the Stack community, but I've finally figured it out.

This is what I ended up with:

**AngularJS**

```
/* Submit */
$scope.submit = function() {
  var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: 'xxx/submit.php',
    data: {
      id: '1',
      coachName: 'B',
      contractArea: '2',
      attendance: 'C',
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  });
};
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

  $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $request = json_decode($postdata);
  $id = $request->id;
  $coachName = $request->coachName;
  $contractArea = $request->contractArea;
  $attendance = $request->attendance;

  $servername = 'xxx';
  $username = 'xxx';
  $password = 'xxx';
  $dbname = 'xxx';

  $conn = new Mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    mail( "adamwadsworth@xxx.com", "DB connect error", $db->connect_errno . ": " . $db->connect_error );
  }
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO participants (id, coachName, contractArea, attendance) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' );
  $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $id, $coachName, $contractArea, $attendance);

  $stmt->execute();

  echo 'Success';

  $stmt->close();

  $conn->close();

?>
```

**SUCCESS**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was also using AngularJS and PHP in one of my project and faced the same problem, then I came across something like this. try to add `headers` parameter in your request. May be this will help you.

```
var variableName = {'id':'3','coachName':'1','contractArea':'2','attendance':'4'})
$http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : "XXX/submit.php",
        data   :  variableName,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function(){
               console.log('Success');
           },function(){
               console.log('Error');
        });
```

I am just trying if it doesn't solve your problem please let me know.

Comment: you have to serialize the data yourself if you switch content type

Comment: @GirdhariAgrawal on submit, the console says success. but when reviewing the database nothing gets added. unless I replace the $_POST values e.g $id = '1'; once I replace all the $_POST values data is successfully pushed to the database.

Answer (score -1):

Updated answer

**Angular** :

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    $http.post('test.php', {'id':'3','coachName':'1','contractArea':'2','attendance':'4'})
        .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            if(!data.success)
                 alert(data.message)
            console.log(data);
        });
}
```

**PHP**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    header('Content-Type:application/json');

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    $servername = 'xxx';
    $username = 'xxx';
    $password = 'xxx';
    $dbname = 'xxx';

    try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO participants (id,coachName, contractArea, attendance) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
                $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    try {

        $dbh->beginTransaction();

        $sth->execute(array(
                        $data->id,//if id is string replace $data->id to '".$data->id."'
                        '".$data->coachName."',
                        '".$data->contractArea."',
                        '".$data->attendance."'
                    ));

        $dbh->commit();

        echo json_encode(['success'=> true,'data'=>$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)]);

    } catch(PDOExecption $e) {
        $dbh->rollback();
        echo json_encode(['success'=>false,'message'=>$e->getMessage()]);
    }
} catch( PDOExecption $e ) {
    echo json_encode(['success'=>false,'message'=>$e->getMessage()]);
}
```

It should work

Comment: `$_POST` will be empty unless change front end to send form encoded data

Comment: @charlietfl I believe this is whats happening, if I replace the $_POST with values e.g '2' this gets pushed to the database, but when using $_POST nothing gets pushed to the database - not even an empty value. Have you any further suggestions ?

Comment: @Adam using `file_get_contents()` should work fine. Try putting `echo json_encode($data); exit;` right after it and see what gets returned as response data...should be identical to what you sent.

Comment: @Adam i understand , your problem into your database table column types.You have to check them.If your id is integer you have to set id column as integer.Example id INT(11) ->VALUES($id,  ...,
but if id VARCHAR or TEXT or another text type " VALUES('$id',  ...,".